# Call to undefined relationship [] on model []

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I have made hasOne relationship in my Model and it is working fine with following query in driver controller:

```
$drivers = Driver::with('vehicleInfo')->first()->toArray();
```

Driver Model:

```
   <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Driver extends Model
{

    // from_location_id
    public function vehicleInfo()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Vehicle','id','vehicle_id');
    }

}
```

But when I try to use same code in AuthController which is generated by Laravel Auth it is giving me error of undefined relationship.

I have included model in AuthController. Which is as follows:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\User;
use App\Role;
use App\Driver; 

class AuthController extends Controller
{

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'mobile' => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string',
            'remember_me' => 'boolean'
        ]);
        $credentials = request(['mobile', 'password']);
        if(!Auth::attempt($credentials))
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Unauthorized'
            ], 401);

        $user = $request->user();
        // print_r($user);
        $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
        $token = $tokenResult->token;

        if ($request->remember_me)
            $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(1);

        $token->save();

        $user_details = User::find($user->id);
        if($user_details->actual_user_id>0){
            // find driver details
            // var_dump(Driver::with('vehicleInfo'));
            $driver_details = Driver::with('vehicleInfo')->first()->toArray();
            // var_dump($driver_details);
        }else{
            $driver_details = "";
        }

        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $tokenResult->accessToken,
            'token_type' => 'Bearer',
            'expires_at' => Carbon::parse(
                $tokenResult->token->expires_at
            )->toDateTimeString(),
            'user_details'=>$user_details->toArray(),
            'driver_details'=>$driver_details
        ]);
    }
}
```

My relationship is public.

Please help.

Comment: Can i see your AuthController code please? Additionally, may I know your Laravel version as well please?

Comment: See the updated question

Comment: could you remove toArray and check if it work?

Comment: already tried not working

Comment: Anybody answer please!!

Comment: Looks correct to me. You can try moving the `with` to the model by setting the property `protected $with = ['vehicleInfo'];` and removing the `with()` in your controller.

Comment: I didn't understand how you are saying.

Comment: What happens if you just to $driver_details = Driver::first();   Just for testing did you try $driver_details = Driver::get(); and still you see errors?

Comment: I believe you are authenticating your API logins right? If you are authenticating your API that is not the right way to authenticate.

Comment: No I get only error when using with

Comment: @Thomas still unable to solve my problem.